# What are the default rules used by checkstyle?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, suppress-warnings, maven-checkstyle-plugin

If I don't define a checkstyle config then a couple of checkstyle rules are executed by default, is there a list of default rules used by checkstyle?

This is how my maven config looks like:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default configuration is using the predefined ruleset "Sun Microsystems Definition" in `sun_checks.xml`, see [Maven Checkstyle Plugin docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-checkstyle-plugin-LATEST/examples/custom-checker-config.html):

> There are 2 predefined Checkstyle configuration definitions that ship with the Checkstyle Plugin, the Sun Microsystems Definition is selected by default.
>
> - sun_checks.xml - Sun Microsystems Definition (default).
> - google_checks.xml - Google Definition.

The contents of the ruleset can be found at [Checkstyle's GitHub repository](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml).

Comment: This is the default configuration by maven-checkstyle-plugin. If you use checkstyle directly, there is no default config.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the rules on official github https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/tree/master/src/main/resources and read the descriptions on the official website https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks.html

Comment: Link-only answers may become useless over time if the link(s) stop working. It's more helpful to directly quote the relevant information in your answer anyway, and provide the links as supplemental information.